# Micromax Doodle 1 A111 device not recognized in Eclipse and in adb shell

Tags: android

I recently bought Micromax Doodle 1 A111 for android development. When I connect the device to my laptop over USB, from eclipse SDK as well as ADB  shell, the device is not getting listed. I am desperate in overcoming this. Please help.

Comment: This has been covered many times here and in other forums; you need to find the VID & PID of the device and use these with a generic ADB driver.

Comment: Have u find the solution ? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the problem by installing  **Moborobo** ! & no restarting required after installing Moborobo , just direct run ! :)

Comment: thanks a lot. moborobo did the magic. cant believe that its working :) sorry for the delay in responding

Comment: can you please post a link to the apk? I am not able to find it.